# Facebook like button don't post back to facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

I have added facebook like button into my site (xfbml) and all necessary meta tag (app_id, title, type, url, image, site_name, desc) by og. When I clicked the like button, whether I specified the comment or not, I see that the like count is increased but nothing post to my facebook. Until I use the LINT tool to debug, the post appeared as I wanted. So that I think the problem is facebook don't scrape my page at the very first time. I read from developer page:

> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter.

I have waited more than 24 hours, but nothing happen until I use Linter. But for any link that I have use Linter, facebook like button work perfectly. Can anyone help me with this problem? My site is nearly to be deployed in production, but I can't not solve it. I took me 4 days already.

My site also uses Spring Social to login with facebook authentication.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : XXXXXXXX, 
        status : true, 
        cookie : true, 
        xfbml : true
    });

};

(function(d, debug) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "")
            + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/false));
```

And in my html:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/abc" send="true" width="460" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<fb:comments href="http://example.com/abc" num_posts="5" width="460"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the xml namespace

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

at the beginning of your document??? Why not use iframes instead??? Worked better from me...

Answer (score 0):

As provided by the facebook developers :

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=500886696626919";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Add an XML namespace to the  tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<fb:like href="http://www.frisianallies.nl" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

if you add these things to your site everything will work and you can even tweak them them css.